# Should I delete my answer if it matches an earlier "faster gun" answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Suppose a fairly simple question comes up that people deem worth answering.  Unfortunately, it has a rather simple solution and leads to a "Fast Gun in the West" scenario.  And while I'm putting my answer together, someone else answers the question.  I post my answer, only to realize that a faster gun beat me.

Would it be proper to delete my now duplicate answer (assuming there isn't much I can do to edit it to make it distinct from the other answer)?

Or should I just leave it as a duplicate?

Comment: @peege I agree, I just couldn't come up with the search terms to even find that question.

Comment: I only got it because I asked this question a few weeks ago.  I'd link to it, but it was linked to the duplicate, and it's all pretty much stating the same thing.  If you added anything of value, leave it for sure.  If it's exactly the same, some think you should leave it to illustrate that it's a commonly known solution.  I left my answer because it had a point the accepted fast gun answer didn't.  If neither was selected as an answer, you can revise your answer to be the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The choice is yours.  There are lots of people that make either choice.  Neither is *wrong*.

If you think that your answer isn't actually helpful, you're welcome to delete it.

If you think your answer is helpful, you're welcome to keep it.

If you're compelled to edit the answer and make it even better, great.

Comment: Ok so if I feel that I can't (or don't want to) improve my answer/explanation  any, is there any downside to deleting the answer (assuming it hasn't received any helpful comments etc.)?  I figure since I'm not intending to improve it, it's just clutter.

Comment: @ryanyuyu No; you're more than welcome to delete it if you see it as not adding any value.

Answer (score 3):

A distinct answer doesn't need to have a unique solution.  It might have the same solution, just explained in a different way, or with better examples.  2 similar solutions that have very different explanations can be helpful because if someone doesn't understand the solution in the first answer, they might understand when explained differently.