# If my answer is a duplicate, should I delete it?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

If I answer a question at almost the exact same time someone else does with almost the exact same words ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069515/what-are-the-5-secret-keywords-in-go/39069548#39069548)) and his answer gets Accepted Answer. Should I then delete my duplicate answer or should I leave it as it is?

Comment: Why should you need to delete it?

Comment: If you think it adds nothing to the question, then you should probably delete it. You are, however, under no obligation to do so.

Comment: @Cerbrus To avoid having too much visual pollution for future readers with the same answer answered twice.

Comment: @RyanB: I'd argue that your answer is better, as it provides a better explanation.

Comment: You could also expand your answer with more information/explanation and try to make it better than the accepted answer.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252795)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing own answer posted few seconds after someone else's and is essentially the same](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252451/removing-own-answer-posted-few-seconds-after-someone-elses-and-is-essentially-t) or http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283005/should-i-delete-my-answer-if-it-matches-an-earlier-faster-gun-answer